# How do I get root in terminal?

Tags: root, permissions

I'm trying to install git with

```
apt-get install git
```

it then says

```
E: Could not open lock fine /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Always do

```
sudo apt-get <command>
```

To drop into root,

`sudo -i` or `sudo su` (`sudo -i` is recommended and more proper, but it really doesn't matter)

Answer (score 4):

to get into the you need to type the following command

```
$ sudo su
```

when prompted for password enter it.You can also use another command that is

```
$sudo -i
```

Comment: `sudo su` is completely unnecessary. Keep to `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 3):

To execute any command as root just start with `sudo` then type the command
You will be asked for your password, the characters won't be shown, not even in dots, so just type the password and hit enter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should install git with root privilege. You can do it by typing `sudo -i` in terminal and then type password if it asks then you can run `apt-get install git`.

If root privilege is only the problem then this should work. Hope this works for you.

Comment: thank you it worked :D I didn't have to type the "sudo" part of the get-apt to get it to work.

Comment: actually after being as a root user you don't have to type `sudo`